# How can I create the equivalent of an explode() USING set data in each different column using WPS office or any others

Tags: excel, csv, google-sheets, spreadsheet, xlsx

I have the following default data set:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I convert from **.TXT** to **.CSV** format but I get one row of all data. how can divide into a different row?

I have 200 000 data.

My default CSV data :

```
A

ath;006400005;1
```

I want to CSV data :

```
A       B           C

ath     006400005   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate it by comma, not semicolon.

From your **.txt** file, find and replace "**;**" to "**,**" then convert it to **.csv**

Comment: But how can I separate it

Comment: From your .txt file, search and replace ; to , then convert it to .csv

Answer (score 1):

in GS:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A; ";")))
```

[image]